# Spring 4 using Groovy setup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy, spring-4

Spring 4.0 has improved support for Groovy e.g. using the GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.

What would be setup to to have a full Spring MVC application using Groovy?
E.g. using GroovyBeanDefinitionReader and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext together.

Anyone knows if there is a sample available or some pointers on a blog site?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out spring boot, still in milestone release behind Spring 4 but they were really pushing its groovy support at spring eXchange.

Check out the bottom of this [spring-boot guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#_jar_support_and_groovy_support)

It's not quite the use of GroovyBeanDefinitionReader and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext you asked for,  but I can't see why you couldn't do what you are after with the *opinionated* approach used by spring boot and the standard configuration annotations on groovy classes.

The git hub repository shows a number of annotated groovy examples
with [ui.groovy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-cli/samples/ui.groovy) for example, showing a configuration class for the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter defining a bean.

Comment: Actually Spring Boot does now have support for `GroovyBeanDefinitionReader` (it didn't yet at the Spring eXchange). Any `*.groovy` source file is interpreted as a `beans{}` DSL , and in the Groovy CLI you can add `beans{}` to any source file they will be added as well (e.g. see [beans.groovy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-cli/samples/beans.groovy)).

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, do `SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{JavaConfig.class, "beans.groovy"}, args)`, where JavaConfig contains your configurations in java (like @Configuration, @ComponentScan and etc., I generally find these things are easier using annotations) and `beans.groovy` just contain your spring beans DSL.

Assuming `beans.groovy` is on classpth (i.e. under src/main/resources)